# Defining the Maximum in Pascal

Tags: pascal

I have another question as this code does not work in the compilers... sorry for the many questions, I think other questions will follow:

```
program findMaximum(input,output);

var
    number, Maximum: integer; 
begin
    writeln('Insert a number and finish up with 0').
    while number < >0 do
    begin
        if number> Maximum then
            Maximum := number;
        readln(number)
    end;
    if Maximum <> 0 then 
        writeln('The biggest number is',Maximum)
    else
        writeln('The input was zero.')
end.
```

Comment: sorry for the writing. It is indented. i still need to learn how to post code here that is actually shown indented.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is there an error message?

Comment: The output is "identifier" expected but "WHILE" found. Before I had a run where I was told Fatal: Syntax error, ";" expected but "identifier Maximum" found.
In both cases there is a syntax error.*it says*

Comment: As the compiler says, statements end with a ";", not ".". Also initialize "maximum" before using it, set it to 0. Also you have to "readln" once before using "number".

Comment: If you learn to actually read the words in the error message, you can solve these problems yourself in the future.

Answer (score -3):

```
var
number, Maximum: integer; 
begin
maximum:=0;
writeln('Insert a number and finish up with 0');
while number < >0 do
begin
readln(number);

if number> Maximum then Maximum := number;
end;

if Maximum <> 0 then 
    writeln('The biggest number is',Maximum)
else
    writeln('The input was zero.')
end.
```

Comment: The line with the first writeln should end with a semicolon, no with a dot.